# Objective-C – access extern const with a string containing its name?

Tags: objective-c, constants, extern, static-variables

I have a constant defined out of class in SomeClass.h:

```
extern NSString *const SCImportantString;

@interface SomeClass

@end
```

And assign it in SomeClass.m:

```
NSString *const SCImportantString = @"All your base are belong to us.";

@implementation SomeClass

@end
```

Is there a way to access this extern constant by a string with its name? I know this is possible with class and instant variables using the `valueForKey:` method.

It would turn very useful to do this while using different build configurations.

Comment: Why don't you create a dictionary for that?

Comment: Could you be more specific? I would basically like to access this constant from code simply by using `SCImportantString` (as preferred in iOS frameworks), as well as simply have strings `SCImportantString` and `SCDifferentImportantString` in a setting for different build configurations. I want to avoid putting the content of the constant there literally, because when someone changes the content, he will definitely forget to change it in the build configuration.

Comment: Or simply use #define...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If get what you are saying there is no builtin way to get the const pointer value from a string ... so there isnt NSConstantFromName(@"xy)

you could it yourself though

```
NSString *const SCConstantByName(NSString *name) {
    if[(name isEqualToString:@"SCImportantString"])
        return SCImportantString;
}
```

or for many have a static dict... like the localizables also work:

```
NSString *const SCConstantByName(NSString *name) {
    id dict = nil;
    if(!dict) {
        dict = @{@"SCImportantString", SCImportantString};

    return dict[name];
}
```

Comment: A bit disappointing, but thanks anyway. In the end, I decided to create a class to handle this for me.