# Dynamically reference const (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

Is it possible to dynamically reference a constant in objective c:

e.g. `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is declared in UIKit/NSAttributedString.h as a `const NSString`. Its value is `@"NSColor"`. In compiled code, I just specify the constant to use it, but what if I need to refer to it dynamically at run time (say a user might type it out)?

I could just use `@"NSColor"`, but that may change as the SDK changes.

Is there a function like `NSClassFromString`, say `ConstFromString`:

```
ConstFromString(@"NSForegroundColorAttributeName") --> @"NSColor"
```

Comment: In which scenarios would a user be typing in a constant name? I'm not sure what your use-case is here, but it sounds like a worse user experience than presenting a value spinner + colour-picker.

Comment: E.g. being able to tweak the color of a label remotely (say the app hits a url that returns `{"textLabel.attributedText.attributes. NSForegroundColorAttributeName":"0xFFFFFF"}`. No recompilation/app update needed

Comment: Since you can't assign attributed text attributes exactly like your input, you're going to have to have logic run after the initial parsing of the input anyway, so why not just put in a switch/case for `attributes` keys?

Comment: In that case you'll want to just define your json scheme to be something simple: `"myControl" : { "color" : "0xFFFFFF" }` and then in your code you map `"color"` to `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.  Since your code is compiled against a specific SDK, this will always work.

Comment: @jeffamaphone  agreed. But the mappings have to be defined manually, there's no lookup function for NSForegroundColorAttributeName?

Comment: @IanMacDonald just wanted to save on some extra tedious typing=potential for mistakes

Comment: No, but you could always use the `textColor` property and use `NSSelectorFromString()` if you really can't stand having to type out a property mapping.  Or get an intern to do it.

Comment: See also [ObjC access extern const with a string containing its name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13883330)

Answer (score 0):

If the symbol is a public, exported symbol, then you *might* be able to look it up at runtime using `dlsym` and friends, but I agree with the commenter that this sounds like a bad idea.